# MSP430F5xx SYSBSLPE behavior after different reset events

Tags: msp430

### Background:

[According to page 90 of SLAU208](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau208o/slau208o.pdf#page=90) SYSBSLPE is 0 after a reset. But this seems to only be the case for a BOR.

[According to page 4 of SLAA450](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa450c/slaa450c.pdf#page=4) the BSL protect function is called after a BOR from the boot code. This is pointed to by the BSL Protection function vector at 0x17F2.

[There is a note on the TI processor wiki that says that the boot code only executes after a hardware triggered BOR](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Custom_MSP430_BSL#Device_Startup_Sequence) and not after setting PMMSWBOR.

### Question:

- If I implement my BSL protect function such that I boot into the bootloader, and then from the bootloader trigger a software POR or PUC when the bootloader is complete, will SYSBSLPE automatically get set to 1 somehow to protect the bootloader?
- What about a software triggered BOR - does that change the situation at all?
- If I set SYSBSLPE to 1 from the bootloader, what will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the SYSBSLPE description, the bootcode sets SYSBSLPE when it finds a BSL.
("Bootcode" means some internal, undocumented code that is executed before the BSL.)

So if you implement your BSL, you will never see a cleared SYSBSLPE.

In the BSL protect function, you can reset SYSBSLPE (if you want to), or change any other fields in the SYSBSLC register.

Comment: What about from the BSL Protection function? I am assuming while that is executing SYSBSLPE is still 0. Or does the BSL protection function need to clear SYSBSLPE?

Comment: I assume BSP Protect can be located in the BSL segments (its vector certainly is). To confirm based on your answer: I can clear SYSBSLPE in the protect function and return 0x2 in R12. At that point the boot code will jump to the address stored at 0x17FA - the BSL start vector. In this situation, SYSBSLPE should still be clear. In this situation is clearing SYSBSLPE even necessary since the boot code is what is actually doing the jump to BSL?

Comment: The BSL protection protects against accesses from the application code.